# Web.Config error

Tags: web-config

i want to add DotNetNuke website functionality in NopCommerce project, so i have added DotnetNuke folders,web.config,pages(ASP.Net VB) at admin folder in Nopcommerce(Asp.net c#) project.

i have two web.configs one at in admin Folder and other is in Root
i have added DotnetNuke web.config in Root web.config of Nopcommerce

my error is

Cannot register or retrieve components until ComponentFactory.Container is set
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Is my process correct.if not then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of stuff in the NopCommerce web.config file that is needed for it to function properly. It sounds like you just replaced the NopCommerce root web.config with the DNN web.config, which is a major no-no. (I could be wrong about what you did, but that's what it sounds like?)

Judging from what you're looking for, it sounds like you might be more interested in a Virtual Folder in IIS. It will allow to separate your web applications and have separate web.config files.

[Here's an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx) on creating Virtual Directories in IIS 7

[Here's one](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5adfcce1-030d-45b8-997c-bdbfa08ea459.mspx?mfr=true) for IIS 6.